# Calculate probability estimate P(y|x) per sample x in scikit for LinearSVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am training my dataset using linearsvm in scikit. Can I calculate/get the probability with which a *sample is classified under a given label*?

For example, using `SGDClassifier(loss="log")` to fit the data,  enables the predict_proba method, which gives a vector of probability estimates `P(y|x)` per sample `x`:

```
>>> clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log").fit(X, y)
>>> clf.predict_proba([[1., 1.]])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.0000005,  0.9999995]])
```

Is there any similar function which I can use to calculate the prediction probability while using `svm.LinearSVC` (multi-class classification). I know there is a method `decision_function` to predict the confidence scores for samples in this case. But, is there any way I can calculate probability estimates for the samples using this decision function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `LinearSVC` will not compute probabilities because it's not trained to do so. Use `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`, which uses the same algorithm as `LinearSVC` but with the log loss. It uses the standard [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for probability estimates:

```
1. / (1 + exp(-decision_function(X)))
```

(For the same reason, `SGDClassifier` will only output probabilities when `loss="log"`, not using its default loss function which causes it to learn a linear SVM.)

Comment: the reason I use `LinearSVC` is that I need an `l1` regularization, so this solution doesn't apply.

Comment: @adrin: `SGDClassifier` has that. It even has elastic-net (mixed l1/l2) regularization.

Answer (score 1):

Multi class classification is a one-vs-all classification. For a `SGDClassifier`, as a distance to hyperplane corresponding to to particular class is returned, probability is calculated as

```
clip(decision_function(X), -1, 1) + 1) / 2
```

[Refer to code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80b96bcfc76fd2e989f487a120fc0699d7d0e2c8/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L658) for details.

You can implement similar function, it seems being reasonable to me for LinearSVC, althrough that probably needs some justification. Refer to paper mentioned in docs

> Zadrozny and Elkan, “Transforming classifier scores into multiclass probability estimates”, SIGKDD‘02, http://www.research.ibm.com/people/z/zadrozny/kdd2002-Transf.pdf

P.s. A comment from ["Is there 'predict_proba' for LinearSVC?"](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1783):

> if you want probabilities, you should either use Logistic regression or SVC. both can predict probsbilities, but in very diferent ways.

Comment: That code is the probability prediction for Huber loss. It is invalid for any other loss, and in fact SGD with `loss="log"` uses a different formula. Neither is valid for SVMs.